# wget -I='/my/subpath,/my/subpath/*' (/my/subpath/) is excluded/not-included. Decided NOT to load it

Tags: linux, wget, webserver, gnu, html

I am trying to index some pages, corresponding to a Documentation.

For that I wanted to

```
wget --no-parent -r -l 5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/
```

But as the request will be redirected to `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript` which is a parent of the previous URL it wont get downloaded.

So I have to do a work-around using -I instead.
For what I learnt that

```
wget \
`## Basic Startup Options` \
  --execute robots=off \
`## Loggin and Input File Options` \
  --output-file=$HOME/wget-last.log \
  --debug \
`## Download Options` \
`## Directory Options` \
`## HTTP Options` \
  --adjust-extension \
`## HTTPS Options` \
  --no-check-certificate \
`## Recursive Retrieval Options` \
  --recursive --level=5 \
`## Recursive Accept/Reject Options` \
  -I=/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript,/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/* \
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
```

That have done the job on previous websites.
But now it looks like to get stuck on tags like

```
<a href="/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Tutorials"><strong>Tutorials</strong></a>
```

Showing the following debug message

```
Deciding whether to enqueue "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Tutorials".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Tutorials (en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is excluded/not-included.
Decided NOT to load it.
```

And that goes on for the rest of files that should be downloading